# removing content on website before a screen reader can read it with either JavaScript or CSS...?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, screen-readers

I'm in charge of this website - http://reader.ku.edu [edit: I've removed the affending menu] - and we're a reading service for blind people, so we need the website to be really good for screen readers.

The website is hosted by a university and we use their Drupal template, which includes a university-wide menu at the very top of the page (email, blackboard, etc., and a very large directory menu).

We need to remove the menu from the website such that screen readers won't start reading it (it's a very large menu).

I have CSS and Javascript permissions, but not PHP.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Would a screen reader read something with `style="display:none"` ? I would think that would be better than `style="visibility:hidden"`. Should that be entered in a CSS document, or executed via javascript? Ala `$('.ku-menu').display.toggle();`

Thanks!

Comment: So you can not alter the template?

Comment: @epascarello no I cannot, it's a Drupal multisite configuration and I have user access to our Drupal website but I do not have server access to the PHP files. All the sites within the multisite share the same template files so if I changed it on our site, it would change it on all sites

Comment: https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/ answers your concerns quite well. Don't hide the nav, that actually hinders accessibility. Try using the site without a mouse/touchscreen to get a good idea of how screen readers will behave. If you do hide it, make sure to use ARIA attribs to let those in need know what's going on.

Comment: thank you @dandavis but there is already a skip nav link, but folks are still complaining

Comment: consider a [screen-reader-only](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/accessibility/#visually-hidden-content) suggestion to bookmark http://reader.ku.edu/#main-content instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove the menu from the DOM, you can do this:

**Pure JavaScript version**

```
document.getElementById("ku_main_nav").remove();
```

**jQuery version**

```
$("#ku_main_nav").remove();
```

The result is, the menu is not visible anymore, but even more, it's not present anymore in the DOM:

Before the JS:

```
<div class="content clearfix" style="font-size: 14px !important; line-height: 16.8px !important;">
  <ul class="inline-list" id="ku_main_nav" style="font-size: 14px !important; line-height: 28px !important;">
    [...]
  </ul>
</div>
```

After the JS:

```
<div class="content clearfix" style="font-size: 14px !important; line-height: 16.8px !important;">

</div>
```

**Edit:**

Added jQuery version

Comment: `document.getElementById("ku_main_nav").remove()` is more succinct and less prone to breaking from tree pruning; gotta love DOM4...